# how to make counter timer faster and how could i change it to start when scrolling down the page, also i want to click out side nav bar to close it

Tags: javascript, navigation, counter

```
const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.mainMenu');
const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.closeMenu');
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.openMenu');

let valueDisplays = document.querySelectorAll(".num"); //for counter
```

// to close nav bar when clicked outside

```
// $(document).on("click" = function(e)){
//   if(e.target.class !== '.mainMenu' && e.target.class !== '.closeMenu'){
//     openMenu.addEventListener('click',close);
//     closeMenu.addEventListener('click',close);
//   }
// }

openMenu.addEventListener('click',show);
closeMenu.addEventListener('click',close);

// valueDisplays.onscroll = function() {countUp()};

let interval = 10000;
```

//function to open and close nav bar

```
function show(){
  mainMenu.style.display = 'flex';
  mainMenu.style.top = '0';
}

function close(){
  mainMenu.style.top = '-100%';
}
```

//counter function - so i want it to count up to the number for example 8407 projected //completed but faster, its very slow right now

```
valueDisplays.forEach((valueDisplay) => {
  let startValue = 0;
  let endValue = parseInt(valueDisplay.getAttribute("data-val"));
  let duration = Math.floor(interval / endValue);
  let counter = setInterval(function () {
    startValue += 1;

    valueDisplay.textContent = startValue;
    if (startValue == endValue) {
      clearInterval(counter);
    }
  }, duration);
});
```